# Check if a file matches a wildcarded spec, in a given directory, with PHP

Tags: php

I have a directory that files are uploaded to, and I want to be able to display a download link if the file exists. The file however has to match a particular pattern as this is the identifier of who uploaded it.

The pattern starts with /ClientFiles/ then it needs to find all files that starts with the user ID. So for example: /ClientFiles/123-UploadData.xls

So it would need to look in the ClientFiles directory and find all files that start with '123-' no matter what comes after.

Cheers

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to have a directory for each user?

Comment: I think you need a [DirectoryIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php), since you need wildcarding. Plenty of examples on that page. (And yes, @twall is right - you need to show you've given questions a good go first - it is the best way to learn).

Comment: @halfer: for a simple match, `glob('123-*.xls')` is far simpler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To look for files by a certain pattern you can use [glob](http://co.php.net/glob), then use is_readable to check if you can read the files.

```
$files = array();    
foreach(glob($dirname . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $clientId . '-*' as $file) {
    if(is_readable($file) {
        $files[] = $file;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply use the [file_exists()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) function

Comment: Better to use is_readable(). Otherwise you can get files that exist, but can't be served.

Answer (score 0):

php has a function file_exists.  Use that to make some logic about if you show a link or not.